# 16.04 ownership nobody:nogroup

Tags: 16.04, permissions, samba, file-sharing

It appears that after upgrading to 16.04 I constantly have problem with share folder ownership and permission.

I created a folder name `test`, changes its permission to `777`, and shared that folder in local network.

From another machine (Windows), I can view and edit file on that `test` folder, but whenever I edit something on a file in that folder, the ownership and permission change to nobody:nogroup - and therefore I cannot edit it again on my 16.04 machine.

```
test$ ll
total 328
drwxrwxrwx 2 pac   pac      4096 Jan 20 09:59 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 pac   pac      4096 Jan 20 09:32 ../
**-rwxr--r-- 1 nobody nogroup** 326442 Jan 20 09:59 t1.log*
```

Why does it automatically change to `-rwxr--r-- 1 nobody nogroup`? How can I prevent this change so that the permission is always `rwxrwxrwx` and ownership is always `pac:pac` (removing that `nobody:nogroup` annoyance)?

I want to avoid having to do this repeatedly on the folder `test`:

```
$ sudo chown pac:pac . -R
$ chmod 777 . -R
```

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138479/mounting-nfs-owners-are-nobodynogroup) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1774670) to see if these help

Comment: @George thanks, will give a try. Strange is that these all happen on 16.04, before I did not have any issue using 14.04

Comment: @artm, I'm a little bit surprised that this worked for you in 14.04. Samba users and system users are two different things. The same goes for file and directory permissions. With Samba you can configure file and dir permissions per share. See here : https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/AccessControls.html#id2614965 https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html#samba-fileserver-configuration (create mask part).

Comment: @albertj I actually use Nautilus to "Share this folder" and set permissions via "Properties > Permission" option on folder `test` to have "Read and write" for "Others". I did the same before on 14.04 and can edit files freely on both machines. It worked very simple that way, but now it doesn;t on 16.04

Comment: all I need is a way to say "this folder is shared by all users and allow all permissions" so anyone in any machine can access and edit freely - not sure if there is a simple way to do that

Comment: @artm You can try setting the file/dir permissions in the Samba config. For example :      directory mask = 0775
    force group = your-user
    force create mode = 0775
That has pros and cons, but might fix your problem. (Don't forget to restart samba daemons (smbd nmbd) after making changes in the /etc/samba/smb.conf).

Comment: @albertj thanks - could you  make your comment as an answer and instruct in (a bit more details) about the samba config, where is that file, and how to restart samba.

Comment: Aha. Did it work for you now ? Good.

Answer (score 3):

In case of permission problems with Samba shares, it is good to realize that Samba has its own structure for users, as well as file and dir permissions.
If one creates a Samba share, and one wants to restrict access by giving only certain users access to that Samba share, one would normally create Samba users. On the command-line this can be done with the command "smbpasswd".
See for more info :

```
man smbpasswd
```

To add user and file/dir permissions to the Samba configuration, one can edit the smb.conf file located in /etc/samba/

See also here :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide#Samba_Server_Configuration_in_terminal

and for setting permissions, see here :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide#File_Sharing_.28Advanced.29

After editing smb.conf, the Samba server daemons need to be restarted or the reading in of the config file needs to be done (reload).

In some older Ubuntu versions, one could restart both smbd and nmbd,
but in newer Ubuntu versions, the "init" script samba can be restarted.

```
sudo service samba restart
```

In some office environments it can make sense to only do a config reload,
instead of a Samba restart, to avoid possible interruptions for the users.

```
/etc/init.d/nmbd force-reload && /etc/init.d/smbd force-reload
```

This is on some older Ubuntu releases. 
I assume on newer Ubuntu releases :

```
sudo service samba force-reload
```

might work.(Have not tested this yet).

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue relating to file and directory permissions when working with samba and not 16.04. I assume you are setting up a public share and not using logins, and mapping the samba guest user to the user *nobody*.

Since all samba users will be logged in as *nobody*, any file saved will inherit the user *nobody* and group *nogroup*.

Your file `t1.log` that is created by the samba guest user has the permissions **`-rwxr--r--`**, and the owner of that file is **nobody**. Your user *pac* is not able to modify it as it has only read permission for **Others**.

One way to resolve this is to remap the samba guest user to your user *pac*.

Make sure this is set in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
guest account = pac
```

...then change the ownership for all the files in your share folder to user *pac*

```
sudo chown -R pac:pac /path/to/share
```

_

Obviously this won't work in a multiuser environment where some other user other than *pac* needs rw access too.

Some may propose the use of `create mask = 0777` and `directory mask = 0777` in smb.conf for files and directories to be created with -rwxrwxrwx, however in my experience I have found it to be quite unreliable, as over time some files still ended up with some other permissions anyway.

The only reliable solution I have found is to remount the share directory with bindfs to always force 0777 permissions.

First, install bindfs:

```
sudo apt install bindfs
```

Then, create a systemd service file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mount-bindfs.service
```

Paste this in the file:

```
# mount-bindfs systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=Remount directories with different permission
After=mountall.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/bindfs -o perms=0777 /path/to/share /path/to/share"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload systemd, enable the service on boot and start it:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable mount-bindfs.service
sudo systemctl start mount-bindfs.service
```

Do a `ll` on your share folder and everything should appear as `rwxrwxrwx` now.

Comment: Adapted from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460472)

Comment: You can also define `-o perms=0777,user=pac,group=pac` if you want to force ownership on the files too.